# Mongodb database for Android application development

Tags: android, mongodb

I developed a social networking android application but now I want to use MongoDB database for it. Can we use mongodb database for developing android applications? any details or links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the MongoDB Java driver with gradle or the jar directly in your project and query a MongoDB from your app.

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/

There are plenty of examples online.

Comment: While this might be possible it is not a good idea as it would require MongoDB to be exposed directly on the Internet. A better solution is to write an API which the app will interface with over the Internet and have the API server talk to Mongo.

Comment: I supposed you are speaking as CEO of a big multinational Martin. First, not everybody has the full resources to create a layered architecture from the beginning. Second, he did not asked for advice, but for feasibility.  I know enough is not a good practice, specially if you are directly connected to the central bank money printing presses and you can buy a whole datacenter the day 1. I respect your opinion, please respect mine, ok?